# DialogFlow: Adding entity values with brackets

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to add entries to a entity which contains bracket. 
eg: project 1(new)
This throws back an error:

> Error parsing Entity 'project_name': Syntax Error in input 'project
>   1(new)'. Incorrect token '(' at position 32. Brackets can only be used
>   with parameterized entities.

Any solutions how to train it?
Added Image below [Dialog Flow error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSVpD.jpg)

Comment: It is hard to guess without posting your code

Comment: this is not on the code side,... It is on the dialogflow side... When we try to add values to entites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using reserved characters for synonyms (parenthesis are reserved).

You can use them as value so you can retrieve this value with parenthesis but you need to clean it from synonyms, see the image:
[Adding parenthesis to value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Zfu.png) (so in this sample, I must clean parenthesis - "Sinop Br" and "Sinop Brazil" from synonyms but I can preserve parenthesis on the value "Sinop (Br)" so this value can be used at backend)

Best regards